# Preimage of semi-infinite interval — terminology

Tags: soft-question, terminology

For a function $f:\mathcal X \to \mathbb R$ and $L \in \mathbb R$, does the the preimage of the semi-infinite interval

$$ f^{-1}(\infty, L] = \big\{x \in \mathcal X\,:\,f(x) \leq L\big\}$$

have a general name? I.e., like "level set" is used for for $f^{-1}\{L\}$.

I imagine if it exists it may naturally arise in convexity or measure theory.

Comment: Normally,  $f^{-1}(-\infty ,L]$ are called **level sets** and $f^{-1}\{L\}$ are called **fibers** (but sometimes $f^{-1}\{L\}$ are also called level sets, but this is not so common I think).

Comment: I imagine what is normal depends on the area of maths one is working in—which areas did you have in mind? It is curious that your suggestion disagrees with the below answer, and seemingly against the history/intuition of contour lines on a map being at the same "level".

Comment: *"I imagine what is normal depends on the area of maths one is working in"* : I would rather say that it depend on the habit of each person. But at the end, it's not so important as far as you define your vocabulary properly.

Answer (score 0):

[Sublevel set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set#Sublevel_and_superlevel_sets) is a reasonable name for those.